# View is not updating in Ionic 3.5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-view

I'm new to Ionic and I'm using Ionic 3.5 with AngularIO, for my case the problem is after ajax call I'm getting the data from service but the view is not updating in emulator. Though the view is getting render properly in web version.
Here is my component and html

```
export class HomePage {

  private tagService: TagService;
  public tagData: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.tagService = new TagService();
    this.loadTags();
  }

  private loadTags() {
    this.tagService.getTagData().then((data)=>{
      this.tagData = data;alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }, ()=>{
      alert("Error occured");
    });
  }

}

<ion-item *ngFor="let tag of tagData" (click)="tagClicked($event)" class="activity" color="positive" data-item="tag">
        {{tag.name}}
        <ion-icon name="{{tag.icon}}" item-right></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
```

The service method is here

```
public getTagData() :Promise<Tag[]> {
        let promise: Promise<Tag[]>;
        promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            $.ajax({
                url: "data/tag.data.json",
                success: (data) => {
                    this.tags = data;
                    resolve(this.tags);
                },
                error: () => {
                    reject();
                }
            });
        });
        return promise;
    }
```

Comment: show the `this.tagService.getTagData()` method

Comment: updated with the service function. BTW if i put an alert with obtained data, its showing properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think you are returning `observable` instead of `promise` from the `loadTags`function. In that case subscribe to an event instead of using `then`

```
private loadTags() {
    this.tagService.getTagData().subscribe((data) => {
        this.tagData = data;
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }, (error) => {
        alert("Error occured");
    })
}
```

do not use jquery `ajax` syntaxes. use angular 2 inbuilt components

```
public getTagData(): any {

    return this.http.get("data/tag.data.jso")
}
```

Comment: I'm getting data from service even in emulator, that's not the problem. Its just the view is not getting rendered in emulator.

Comment: Thanks, using angular components worked. But can you please tell why its not happening if I use Jquery? As I said I was getting data but the view was not updating.

Comment: because jquery ajax will stop the two way binding in angular. so even though result comes to your js it will not bind to the view. that is why always use angular in build components